# Something similar to the dual map

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, terminology

The dual map is defined as follows:
$$f^*(\varphi) = \varphi \circ f$$

I came across something similar:
$$f_*(\varphi) = f \circ \varphi$$

Is there some name for the second map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map like that is typically called either a **pushforward** map or a **post-composition** map.